# Looping through multiple variables in a function

Tags: javascript

I've written a function that contains an if statement and the condition contains a variable.

```
    function interval() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (x < max) {
                x = parseInt(x) + 1;
                $('.max').html(addCommas(x));
            }
        }, 1);
    };
```

So here *max* is my variable. Works great, but now I have three more variables and I want to run the same function but with the different variables each time. I could copy the function 3 more times and edit the variable in each one but that strikes me as highly inefficient.

What would be the best way to achieve this Stacked?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a `for` or `while` loop? `setInterval` seems like the wrong solution here

Comment: Why _parseInt(x)_ - and if x might not be a number shouldn't you do the parsing _before_ comparing it to max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass max as an argument to the function

```
function interval(max){
    var x = 0; //always declare variables
    var interval = setInterval( function(){
    if (x < max){
        x = parseInt(x) + 1;

        $('.max').html(addCommas(x));
        }
    }, 1);
};
```

I'm not sure of the driver for putting this code in an interval.  You may want to consider using a for loop:

```
function interval(max){
    for(var x = 0; x < max; x++){
       $(".max").html(addCommas(x));
    }        
};
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It's an animated counter that's why it's in an interval. I'm not sure how adding the variable to the function's argument is helping me?

Comment: @user1635375 - An interval delay of 1 is overkill for animation. The browser won't actually go that fast (most if not all will round it up to 4 or 5).

Comment: @user1635375 I assume you wanted to run the function for different max values, add one of the other functions you would create to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameters in function and use same function.

```
function interval(vfield){
    var interval = setInterval( function(){
    if (x < vfield){
        x = parseInt(x) + 1;

        $('.max').html(addCommas(x));
        }
    }, 1);
};
```

Where vfield is your variable.